# How can I match all alphanumerical characters and the underscore, the plus, the minus and the decimal point?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to use a string that come from a machine to create a folder and file names. The machine is a wafer prober. The folder and file can be present on Windows and Linux OS.
How can I remove all characters except +, -, ., _ and all the alphanumerical characters with regular expressions in (Iron)Python? So far I got to the following. But that is not containing ., - or + .

```
>>> re.sub(r'[\W]+', '', ':LOT002_Temp<3.00000E+01>')
'LOT002_Temp300000E01'
```

I would like the answer to be the following:

```
'LOT002_Temp3.00000E+01'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: `+` is a non-word character. So is `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negation based character class:

```
re.sub(r'[^\w.+-]+', '', ':LOT002_Temp<3.00000E+01>')
'LOT002_Temp3.00000E+01'
```

`[^\w.+-]` will match any non-word character that is not `+`, `-` or `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://rubular.com/ they're great for prototyping regex's

```
$ python
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w\+\.]+' , '', ':LOT002_Temp<3.00000E+01>')
'LOT002_Temp3.00000E+01'
```

Comment: Ah didn't know about that one.. Cool. Old habits die hard. When i think regex i think rubular. hahah! Thanks though, i'll book mark it.